# Change the default url directory for all the links on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, yetanotherforum

I need some help. Thanks in advance.

I got the Open source code of YAF Forum (yetanotherforum.net)

I integrated it in my website application.

I have a small problem when I debug on localhost. I'll try to be clear.

The link in the forums all point to

```
~/Yaf/linkurl.aspx
```

(linkurl is the page name)
But they only work if I remove the /Yaf/. So I want all the links to point only to

```
~/linkurl.aspx
```

Where can I change that? is that in a config file or someplace else?

I hope I was clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding

```
<add key="YAF.FileRoot" value="~/"/>
```

To the app.config file

Answer (score 0):

Change `YAF.BaseUrl` key's value from **"~/yaf/"** to **"~/"**

[Embedding YAF inside an existing asp.net website](http://wiki.yetanotherforum.net/embeddedYaf.ashx?Discuss=1)

Comment: Thank you for your responce. But do you have an idea where to find it? I didn't find it anywhere. I also tried adding it as a key in app.config but still the same problem.